# How to check which GPU is active in Linux?

Tags: linux, hardware, graphics

I have 2 GPU's in my netbook. How do I know which one I'm actually using at any given moment?

Answer (score 86):

I've just gone through a hell of a time
trying to get my discrete graphics to work in Ubuntu,
and answering this question was constantly a challenge,
since the lspci method mentioned earlier
can sometimes say that both are `[VGA controller]`.

I think the following command should give you an indication of your active chip:

```
$ glxinfo | grep -E "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile
```

For me, this is telling me that my Intel graphics are running the show.

`glxinfo` is available from the `mesa-utils` package,
so you will need to install it if you haven't already. 
On Ubuntu 22.04, for example, run:

```bash
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

If you're using an NVIDIA chip, and you're using the `bumblebee` package,
you can put `optirun` in front of that line,
and it should tell you that you're running the NVIDIA chip
(`optirun` is basically telling the computer
to use the discrete chip to run whatever command follows,
but everything else is still using the integrated chip).

```
$ optirun glxinfo | grep -E "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 555M/PCIe/SSE2
```

`glxheads` is another helpful command from `mesa-utils` that tells you
some useful information about which graphics card is in use
(mostly repeats `glxinfo` in a more compact and easy-to-read form, though),
and it gives you a nice rendering of a rotating triangle.

Answer (score 31):

To check which GPU is currently in command (that means which is an active VGA controller) type in

```
lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
```

Any controller with `[VGA controller]` at the end is your currently active GPU. The others are switched off. In the following example the Intel card is active while the nVidia one is not in use:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor
Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA 
controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce
GT 540M] [10de:0df4] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
```

Comment: Um... so what does it mean if both cards have `VGA controller` at the end?

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] [10de:11fc] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])          what does it mean?

Comment: Maybe you're using SLI?

Comment: in my case both has that at the end:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:591b] (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] [10de:1c20] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

Comment: In my case, both are end with [VGA controller], so how can I know the exact one?

Comment: This doest work. it lists both on my xmg neo.

Answer (score 12):

**`nvidia-settings` GUI**

On Ubuntu 15.10, after I installed `nvidia-352` and the GPU seems to work:

```
nvidia-settings
```

shows something like:

[image]

Note how it shows:

```
GPU 0 - (NVS 5400M)
```

where `NVS 5400M` is my GPU model.

Then if I fire `glxgears`, the "GPU Utilization" goes to > 90%.

So I expect that if you had multiple GPUs, you could see how much each one was being used at a time.

Comment: What is nvidia-352 exactly? Is is a bunch of drivers or just a driver for a specific GPU?

Comment: @cosbor11 `nvidia-352` is the version of the driver  / Ubuntu package n, each version supports many GPUs as listed on the official website: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/90279/en-uames NVS 5400M is the GPU model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units

Comment: This answer is Nvidia-specific, but the OP didn't specify a vendor. What about AMD? I have an AMD laptop with integrated and dedicated GPUs.

Comment: @unfa sorry, I don't know how to do it there, let me know if you find a more general method, I don't like lock-in either. Also, I like your YouTube channel :-)

Answer (score 11):

```
nvidia-smi -L
```

This gave me what I wanted. This command shows the list of GPUs present on your machine. This might help you figure which are active ones.

got the command from thread here: [Ubuntu Box with multiple NVIDIA GPU Cards | devtalk.nvidia.com](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/865161/ubuntu-box-with-multiple-nvidia-gpu-cards/)

Comment: anybody figured out how to find the free GPUs out of the ones returned by this command?

Comment: Just curious, will this command list an Intel integrated GPU if you decided to disable your Nvidia GPU?

Comment: This only lists Nvidia GPUS and gives no indication if active for desktop or not..

Comment: This answer is Nvidia-specific, but the OP didn't specify a vendor. What about AMD? I have an AMD laptop with integrated and dedicated GPUs.

Comment: Again, this is Nvidia specific. Not a usable answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just type `nvidia-smi` in the terminal. Then check for the percentage of usage. That will indicate which GPU is in use.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Which OS are you using? If you use lspci on most linux machines you get a list of your pci devices, just grep for graphics devices and it should pop up both of them. After that just check out the config on each of them, you should see details of up/on/active or something to that nature.

Comment: ubuntu 11.04. and lspci is showing all two gpu's.

Answer (score 0):

`nvidia-smi` is very useful, but at times I've found that it doesn't always include everything.  It seems when processes crash they aren't always listed.

`sudo lsof /dev/nvidia*` has always worked for me.  It will also work without `sudo`, but will only show processes owned by you.  If you are working on a multiuser machine or are using docker, you will probably get better results with `sudo`.

If you see a discrepancy between the 2 commands, you may want to consider `kill`ing the extra processes found with `lsof`.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04 this can be done from the GUI with the NVIDIA settings application:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found another method, just in case anyone needs to detect the model of your NVIDIA graphics card and the recommended driver.

`ubuntu-drivers devices`

I got this from here:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

Discrete card (DIS) will be Off (or DynOff) when not in use. Integrated card (IGD) is always energized (Pwr).