# How to get information about pc in xfce4

Tags: xfce, desktop-environment

So I just moved to xfce4 and I wanted to know the specs of the pc. I know I can use the terminal but isn't there some gui for it like KDE has an info section and GNOME has an about section isn't there some section like that for xfce4?

Comment: Particularly if you use Ubuntu (Xubuntu with xfce) or Debian (or Linux distros based on those), The [Ubuntu Forum's `system-info` script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/) will provide a lot of detailed information about your hardware and software.

Comment: I'm running xfce on arch linux

Comment: The system-info script can work in Arch too, but some of the details will not be shown, because Arch comes with a different set of default programs (than Ubuntu and Debian). You might find it worthwhile install the programs, that the script wants and get a better result. - But maybe you want a limited set of data, and can find some other tool/method. *Please tell us what data you want*, and I and others can suggest good ways to extract those data.

Comment: Well I want know what gpu is being used my dedicated gpu or integrated one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show details about the graphics processor (GPU) you can install and run `lshw` or `inxi`.

Examples (when I run them),

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK106GL [Quadro K4000]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:56 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

or

```
$ sudo inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GK106GL [Quadro K4000]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.6 drivers: nouveau (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 3840x2160@30.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: NVE6 version: 4.3 Mesa 20.0.8
```

These tools can show a lot more data. See `man lshw` and `man inxi`.

---

Edit: I have another computer (a laptop) with both Intel and Nvidia graphics. If two devices are enabled with drivers, you can check which one is active now with **`glxinfo`**

```
$ glxinfo | egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)
```

In this case the Intel chip is active (and the nvidia chip is passive).

See more details at this link: [How to check which GPU is active in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16407/how-to-check-which-gpu-is-active-in-linux/185062#185062)